# How to make LoadStateAdapter work when phone do not have internet access

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, android-paging, android-paging-3

does anyone know how to show
**LoadStateAdapter**
in the case when the application starts with a disconnected network?
I'm using Paging 3 - 3.0.0-alpha13 (*beta-01 loses keys in my implementation*)

**Situation:**

Added **LoadStateAdapter** to **PagingDataAdapter** as footer

In the case when we receive the status (*LoadState*.**Error**) in **LoadStateAdapter**, for example, in case of network loss, this status makes "**loaderItem**" visible

**loaderItem** is shown when its **displayLoadStateAsItem** method
based on **loadState** will return true.
By default, this happens when **loadState = LoadState.Loading** or **LoadState.Error**

- LoadStateAdapter is added as the footer watches loadState.**append**
- LoadStateAdapter added as Header watches loadState.**prepend**

In cases where the application from a cold start does not have access to the network
**RemoteMediator** throws *MediatorResult*.**Error** ({"*Unable to resolve host ...*"})

The error "arrives" in *loadState*.**mediator** and in *loadState*.**refresh**
append and prepend do not receive errors
have the **NotLoading** status (endOfPaginationReached = false)
**loaderItem** is not shown.

How to correctly get the result when **LoadStateAdapter**
in a cold start situation appeared at the end of the list behind the cached list?

**ps:**
I tried to create my method

```
   fun LoadStateWithBlackJackAndHookers (footer: LoadStateAdapter <*>): ConcatAdapter {
       addLoadStateListener {loadStates ->
                loadStates.mediator? .let {
                    if (it.refresh is LoadState.Error) {
                        footer.loadState = it.refresh
                    }
                }
                footer.loadState = loadStates.append
            }
            return ConcatAdapter (footer, this)
    }
```

It didn’t give the desired result, **LoadStateAdapter** started getting error messages but doesn’t show **loaderItem**

Comment: try/catch? Also please use naming conventions, methods start with lowercase.

Comment: I have try/catch in the RemoteMediator class, if there is no network, then MediatorResult.Error(exception) is triggered. Here is the problem. 
If I use withLoadStateFooter() method to concat with base adapter
and launch app without internet access LoadState.Error is not coming to loadState in LoadStateAdapter class.
 LoadStateAdapter class receive and show error item only when I start app with internet accesses and lose network after few seconds. 
I create my method,  loadState receive LoadState.Error when I need, but item still do not show.

Answer (score 2):

First off for a footer, you  want `ConcatAdapter(this, footer)` (assuming `this` is `PagingDataAdapter`), otherwise your footer will get prepended to the list and actually be a header instead of a footer.

Second the logic here:

```
loadStates.mediator? .let {
  if (it.refresh is LoadState.Error) {
    footer.loadState = it.refresh
  }
}
footer.loadState = loadStates.append
```

Does not return after setting `footer.loadState = it.refresh`, instead it immediately overwrites the value with `footer.loadState = loadStates.append`. I think you want:

```
loadStates.mediator? .let {
  if (it.refresh is LoadState.Error) {
    footer.loadState = it.refresh
  } else {
    footer.loadState = loadStates.append
  }
}
```

But actually, you should listen to mediator.refresh directly if you're customizing logic with `CombinedLoadStates` as the `CombinedLoadStates.refresh` helper does some wild things heuristically to try and guess common desired behavior. Just this directly would be better:

```
if (it.loadStates?.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.Error) {
  footer.loadState = it.refresh
} else {
  footer.loadState = loadStates.append
}
```

As en exciting exercise, you can follow how the helper updates here: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:paging/common/src/main/kotlin/androidx/paging/MutableLoadStateCollection.kt;l=103?q=MutableLoadStateCollection&ss=androidx

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I want to show a retry button on the screen when i first run the app and it have no data on the database and no internet connection. I'm implementing a LoadStateAdapter too, but it does not shows the UI elements when remoteMediator returns MediatorResult.Error. This tips worked? I sincerely didnt understand how to implement it.

Comment: @roooooon can you share your sample or what you tried? Happy to take a look.

Comment: Hi @dlam, thanks on advance for the support. I've implemented a remoteMediator that catches the IOException and the HttpException. When I launch the app with the wifi down, the remoteMediator returns an exception but the observer cant submit the data, becouse there is no data, right. But I dont know how to display the retry button on the UI in that case, since my retry button's and progress bar's visibility are treated on the LoadStateAdapter. https://pastebin.com/Q3S0mwAK

Comment: the paste is private, but PagingData isn't a list of items, you need to submit it to hook up paging and start loading. So as soon your app starts you'll immediately receive a PagingData and submitData starts loading. The default behavior of .withLoadStateHeader / Footer are tied to APPEND and PREPEND states, but you want to listen on REFRESH states for the initial load. Basically you need to implement a listener to similar to my snippet above to catch all the load types you want to display the retry button.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but how do I modify the footer of the adapter, since the addLoadStateListener method is been called from the fragment?

Comment: addLoadStateListener sets the loadState property on LoadStateAdapter, which then determines whether it should bind the footer or not. I'm not sure I understand your question - can you share a sample of what you tried, your previous paste was private so it was impossible for me to view it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are trying to bind multiple footers for different load states, you can also just append multiple LoadStateAdapters to the end for each case.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do, actually. See.. for the cold start of the app with the wifi down the LoadState wont work, so I added the stateListener, as recommended. But I don't know how to add the footer in this case. Also, I'm having a little trouble figuring out witch state to observe (remote or source or both).

Comment: here's a public pastebin of parts of my implementation https://pastebin.com/ynD1CuNs

Comment: So, in summary, my problem is with the app first run with the wifi down. It can have data on Room or not, besides from that, on the cold start, i would like to be able to append the same footer that i'm using in the loadState. The loadStateAdapter works fine but it must have the first run with the wifi ON. After that, if i turn off the wifi, the footer is shown as expected. Is it clear?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on your paste, if you are using `RemoteMediator` to do your network fetch, then the wifi being down / failure  to fetch from network will show up in `CombinedLoadStates.mediator.*`. There is no requirement for wifi to be on for LoadState to work. If you are not using `RemoteMediator`, then you'll need to hook up tracking the network fetch state yourself and then set the `.loadState` property on `LoadStateAdapter`. If you make network calls outside of Paging, LoadState won't be hooked up for you automatically, but you can still use `LoadStateAdapter`.

Comment: after some time i figured out the answer you gave. It's possible to override the LoadStateAdapater.loadState inside the addLoadStateListener. With this conclusion I was able to implement the behavior I was trying to. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!